# Node.js NodeList to XML string

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have some XML data that I need to handle in Node.js. I need to strip an envelope (SOAP) and then just return the payload/body och the envelope.

I get it as a DOM Document into my code and I can easily find the Body content and get that into a NodeList object.

Now I'd like to return the NodeList as a "XML String" but I haven't been able to find any way of doing this... What I basically need is a XML.stringify() (same as JSON.stringify()) but there doesn't seem to be any such function.

I've tried to write a "stringify()" myself but as there are attributes and namespaces in the XML it becomes very tricky...

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out.

```
function nodeListToString(nodeList){
    return [].slice.call(nodeList).reduce((str, x) =>{
        return str+=x.outerHTML;
    }, '');
}
```

calling Array.prototype.slice.call() on a NodeList object converts it to an array, we can then use the arrays reduce method.
reduce then iterates over everything in the array transforming it to the desired formt, [read up on it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Sorry, you can also do [].slice.call() for shorter code.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually not using a "HTML" environment but a plain Node.js implementation so I don't have ".outerHTML" available it seems.

Comment: ah sorry, I haven't done much development is node, and am not sure what soap is. When you say you have a NodeList, is it an array of json objects like whats shown here https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#overriding-the-attributes-key